How to remove space between every three decimals siunitx column format
My code and output are below. It seems like the S column format from siunitx package adds space between every three decimal points, but not always. I am wondering how to "turn off" the feature where the S format adds space every three decimal places.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{
                    |c|
                    S[table-format = 2.7, table-number-alignment = center]|
                    S[table-format = 2.7, table-number-alignment = center]|
                    S[table-format = 2.7, table-number-alignment = center]
                    |S[table-format = 2.3, table-number-alignment = center]|
                }
         \hline
         Atom & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$x$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$z$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{occ.} \\ \hline
         A & 0.24849(8) & 0.25156(8) & 0.66595(9) & 1.00 \\ \hline
         B & 0.2530(2) & 0.7297(3) & 0.50001(4) & 1.00 \\ \hline
         C & 0.2297(3) & 0.7531(2) & 0.33335(4) & 1.00 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }%end resizebox
    \end{center}
    
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:label}
\end{table}

\end{document}

This produces .
See that since entries (B, x), (B, y), (C,x), (C,y) have one less significant figure, there is no space after the thousandths place like there is for the rest of the entries.
So I am wondering if there is a way to "turn off" the feature that is putting the space after the thousandths place.
I have tried adding space after the thousandths place manually with \ and \hspace{1mm}, but this put a massive space in (more than 1mm).
Thanks all

Welcome to TeX.SE.

You can switch off the grouping with group-digits = none:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\sisetup{group-digits = none}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
%    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{
                    |c|
                    S[table-format = 2.7, table-number-alignment = center]|
                    S[table-format = 2.7, table-number-alignment = center]|
                    S[table-format = 2.7, table-number-alignment = center]
                    |S[table-format = 2.3, table-number-alignment = center]|
                }
         \hline
         Atom & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$x$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$y$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$z$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{occ.} \\ \hline
         A & 0.24849(8) & 0.25156(8) & 0.66595(9) & 1.00 \\ \hline
         B & 0.2530(2) & 0.7297(3) & 0.50001(4) & 1.00 \\ \hline
         C & 0.2297(3) & 0.7531(2) & 0.33335(4) & 1.00 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
%    }%end resizebox
    \end{center}
    
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:label}
\end{table}

\end{document}



In addition to adding the instruction \sisetup{group-digits=false} -- \sisetup{group-digits=none} works too -- I suggest you (a) get rid of the unnecessary \resizebox wrappper/sledgehammer, (b) replace the center environment with a \centering instruction, (c) remove all instances of table-number-alignment = center since that's the default, (d) change S[table-format = 2.7] to S[table-format = 1.5(1)] for the first three data columns, and (e) replace
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$x$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$y$} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$z$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{occ.}

in the header row with the much more readable
{$x$} & {$y$} & {$z$} & {occ.}

Finally, I'd add a \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt} instruction to give the table a more open and inviting "look".

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx} % no longer needed 
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
    %%\begin{center}
    \centering
    %%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|
                c|
           *{3}{S[table-format = 1.5(1)]|}
                S[table-format = 1.2] |}
    \hline
    Atom & {$x$} & {$y$} & {$z$} & {occ.} \\ 
    \hline
    A & 0.24849(8) & 0.25156(8) & 0.66595(9) & 1.00 \\ 
    \hline
    B & 0.2530(2)  & 0.7297(3)  & 0.50001(4) & 1.00 \\ 
    \hline
    C & 0.2297(3)  & 0.7531(2)  & 0.33335(4) & 1.00 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    %%}%end resizebox
    %%%\end{center}
    
    \caption{caption}
    \label{tab:label}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Thank you. I wish I could accept more than just one answer.

@elscan - You're most welcome. Do please change all instances of S[table-format = 2.7] to S[table-format = 1.5(1)], and do also change S[table-format = 2.3] to S[table-format = 1.2].
